# Git push/pull fails in GitKraken to/from GitLab (self-hosted)

Tags: git, gitkraken

Getting the error message:

> Fetch failed for 'origin'. Failed to send request: The connection with the server was terminated abnormally

Started happening after GitLab was upgraded by the the ops team.

The "Personal Access Token" seems to be working properly. It's all green and says "Connected". Was also able to add ssh key to my GitLab account from GitKraken using the token...

Edit: If I open terminal from GitKraken and do `git pull` it works, but I had to do a .gitconfig change. Think it might be proxy related, but not entirely sure.

```
[http]
    sslVerify = false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up on https/ssl. I think the proxy is breaking it.

Edited the remote => origin in GitKraken to use ssh instead of https (git@local.gitservername.com:/repopath)